# Ethernet performance through Asix AX88179 in FreeBSD is slow with 1Gbit connection

Tags: freebsd

Setup:

- Dell laptop with USB3.0 ports
- TrueNas (12.2-RELEASE-p2 FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p2 663e6b09467(HEAD) amd64)
- 2 NICs (ugreen usb3.0 to 1Gbit ethernet, with 3 usb ports on it each)

Both devices are being mounted successfully with axge driver. One hdd is attached to 1st device via USB and gets nearly 100Mb/s benchmark (so the USB3.0 hub on each devices is working fine).

```
    root@truenas[~]# ifconfig ue0
    ue0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8000b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,LINKSTATE>
        ether 00:0e:c6:7c:e2:32
        inet 192.168.1.200 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    root@truenas[~]# ifconfig ue1
    ue1: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=80009<RXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,LINKSTATE>
        ether 00:0e:c6:7c:e1:cd
        inet 192.168.1.201 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
```

```
root@truenas[~]# dmesg
...
re0: <RealTek 810xE PCIe 10/100baseTX> port 0x2000-0x20ff mem 0xc1404000-0xc1404fff,0xc1400000-0xc1403fff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci2
re0: Using 1 MSI-X message
re0: ASPM disabled
re0: Chip rev. 0x40800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00400000
miibus0: <MII bus> on re0
rlphy0: <RTL8201E 10/100 media interface> PHY 1 on miibus0
rlphy0:  10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto, auto-flow
re0: Using defaults for TSO: 65518/35/2048
re0: Ethernet address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
...
ugen0.5: <ASIX Elec. Corp. AX88179> at usbus0
axge0 on uhub7
axge0: <NetworkInterface> on usbus0
...
miibus1: <MII bus> on axge0
rgephy0: <RTL8169S/8110S/8211 1000BASE-T media interface> PHY 3 on miibus1
rgephy0:  none, 10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 10baseT-FDX-flow, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, 100baseTX-FDX-flow, 1000baseT-FDX, 1000baseT-FDX-master, 1000baseT-FDX-flow, 1000baseT-FDX-flow-master, auto, auto-flow
ue0: <USB Ethernet> on axge0
ue0: Ethernet address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ugen0.6: <GenesysLogic USB3.1 Hub> at usbus0
uhub8 on uhub1
uhub8: <GenesysLogic> on usbus0
uhub8: 4 ports with 4 removable, self powered
ugen0.7: <ASIX Elec. Corp. AX88179> at usbus0
axge1 on uhub8
axge1: <NetworkInterface> on usbus0
miibus2: <MII bus> on axge1
rgephy1: <RTL8169S/8110S/8211 1000BASE-T media interface> PHY 3 on miibus2
rgephy1:  none, 10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 10baseT-FDX-flow, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, 100baseTX-FDX-flow, 1000baseT-FDX, 1000baseT-FDX-master, 1000baseT-FDX-flow, 1000baseT-FDX-flow-master, auto, auto-flow
ue1: <USB Ethernet> on axge1
ue1: Ethernet address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ugen0.8: <AsmediaASM1051 USB3.0  Serial> at usbus0
umass0 on uhub8
umass0: <AsmediaASM1051 USB3.0  Serial, class 0/0, rev 3.00/1.00, addr 7> on usbus0
umass0:  SCSI over Bulk-Only; quirks = 0xc100
umass0:4:0: Attached to scbus4
(probe0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): REPORT LUNS. CDB: a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00
(probe0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): CAM status: SCSI Status Error
(probe0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): SCSI status: Check Condition
(probe0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): SCSI sense: ILLEGAL REQUEST asc:20,0 (Invalid command operation code)
(probe0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): Error 22, Unretryable error
....
lo0: link state changed to UP
re0: link state changed to DOWN
ue0: link state changed to UP
ue1: link state changed to UP
...
ue0: link state changed to DOWN
ue1: link state changed to DOWN
ue0: link state changed to UP
ue1: link state changed to UP
```

Problem:
when I measure my internet connection through each interface (ue0, ue1) I get up to 60Mbits only, however should be around 300Mbits (that's my ISP tariff).

When I set `ifconfig ue0 media 100baseTX mediaopt full-duplex` to interface I get full 100Mbits connection. But with the default 1000baseT it's working worse providing me with up to 60Mbits.

---

I made a simple test with LiveCD of Ubuntu 18, and I do get the full internet connection with the same setup, meaning that the problem it's none of cables, routers, internet connection provided, usb ports, etc.

---

The AXGE driver is supposed to be working fine, at least the very few results on the internet said that.
I'm really confused with this situation and what is worse there's not so many relevant information on that.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/FreddyXin/ax88179_178a/issues/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## USB Speed verification

The first thing I would look at is the USB part for good measure.

From the snippets you have added we can see that:

```
Mortherbord USB (unknown) -> Unknown (Prabably GenesysLogic) (uhub7) -> axge0 (ugen0.5)
Mortherbord USB (unknown) -> GenesysLogic (uhub8) -> axge1 (ugen0.7)
```

So we have no less than 2 USB chipsets (Dell motherboard, Ugreen hub)and drivers or a combination thereof which could play games with us.

First I would do:

```
grep usbus /var/run/dmesg.boot
```

Here I would look at what USB drivers I am using and what speeds are supported. Is the Dell using regular EHCI, UHCI, OHCI or XHCI driver? Does it show as "Super Speed?

We will be looking for something along the lines of:

```
usbus0: 5.0Gbps Super Speed USB v3.0
usbus1: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
usbus2: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
```

Then I would look at the output of `usbconfig` which tells us the speeds of the different ports.

In your setup I would then try:

```
usbconfig -d ugen0.5 dump_device_desc
usbconfig -d ugen0.7 dump_device_desc
```

Again making sure that you are seeing "Super Speed" for axge0 and axge1.

If you are not seeing "Super Speed" then verify that you see the same speed under Linux. High speed is enough to saturate your 300Mbps.

So the issue *could in theory* be USB related. Maybe the Linux driver have some quirks for your chipset which could explain the difference.

## Other reports

If you are seeing "Super Speed" then I must say that I am seeing worse reports on the Internet than you:

[Bug 225179 - performance issues with axge driver](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225179)

[USB Ethernet adapter (AX88179) Issue](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/usb-ethernet-adapter-ax88179-issue.62016)

## Flow control

There is however another chance. It is most likely only relevant if you only have "High Speed". Try `netstat -i` and see if you have a lot of `Ierrs`. In that case try:

```
ifconfig ue0 media auto mediaopt flow
```

> The command above will re-establish a link with link partner and enables Ethernet flow control.  Check current media with ifconfig(8) after executing the command above.  You should see "rxpause" and "txpause" in media row of ifconfig output when everything goes right. Note, link partner should also support flow control otherwise the command above has no effect.

See [Bug 210488 - ue0 axge AX88179 Ierrs errors under havy network load](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210488)

If I read the dmesg correctly the default is "auto-flow" and the above command changes it to "flow".

## No dice?

If none of the above gets you any further (or there are better answers) then consider chiming in on Bug 225179.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with two of my AX88179 adapters, one in a dock, the other a dingle. I get around 5-6MB/s with it, both under Windows and Linux Live CD. There is some weird bug with these chips, you can find people reporting this when you google about it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/391408)